# error cs0119 expression denotes a type' where a variable' value' or method group' was expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically im writing a script and i get this error.

```
error cs0119 expression denotes a type' where a variable' value' or method group' was expected
```

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BallControl : MonoBehaviour {

    void FixedUpdate () {

        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3);
    }
}
```

Im trying to make a script that will make a sphere (ball) move using WASD or arrow keys. I am following an online tutorial. And i am sure i did evrything correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, you mean to apply `movement` onto the `rigidbody`?

```
//rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3);
rigidbody.AddForce (movement);
```

Comment: I did that and it stopped giving errors, But the script doesnt seem to work with a warning saying the referenced script on this behavior is missing